# How to convert byte array to image in php?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, arrays

I want to convert the byte array from a webservice to image. The webservice response array looks like the following but I could not figure out how to render this array back to an image. Please help me

```
'MemberImage' => 
    array (size=151745)
      0 => int 255
      1 => int 216
      2 => int 255
      3 => int 224
      4 => int 0
      5 => int 16
      6 => int 74
      7 => int 70
      8 => int 73
      9 => int 70
      10 => int 0
      11 => int 1
      12 => int 1
      13 => int 1
      14 => int 0
      15 => int 72
      16 => int 0
      17 => int 72
      18 => int 0
      19 => int 0
      20 => int 255 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to convert data into binary string, es:

```
$data = implode('', array_map(function($e) {
    return pack("C*", $e);
}, $MemberImage));

// header here
// ...

// body
echo $data;
```

Comment: I tried this code but image is  not generate instead its generates the output like this,����JFIFHH��Photoshop 3.08BIM�HH8BIM� 8BIM�H/fflff/ff���2Z5-8BIM�p���

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert that array to an actual byte array (i.e. a *binary string* in PHP) you could use the following function...

```
function arrayToBinaryString(Array $arr) {
    $str = "";
    foreach($arr as $elm) {
        $str .= chr((int) $elm);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

You could also use `pack` instead of the above function to do the same thing like so...

```
call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(['C*'], $arr));
```

or in PHP 5.6+

```
pack('C*', ...$arr);
```

With that you could then - in theory - use the binary string as an image. So, for example, assuming you want to output the raw image data, and that the image is say a `PNG`, you would do something like the following, in conjunction with the above code...

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo arrayToBinaryString($myArray);
```

Just be sure to edit the `Content-type` header with whatever type the actual image is. If you don't know you could use something like `getimagesize` on the binary string to extract the **MIME** type from the image data.

```
$tmpFile = tempnam("/tmp");
$image = arrayToBinaryString($myArray);
file_put_conetnts($tmpFile, $image);
$imageData = getimagesize($tmpFile);
header("Content-type: {$imageData['mime']}");
echo $image;
unlink($tmpFile);
```

Comment: when i run this it shows "Call to undefined function tmpnam()"

Comment: @GokulBasnet Yea, the function is called `tempnam`, that was a typo. I'll correct it.